# Adicionar texto numa determinada posição do texto do input

Tags: javascript

Tenho um input text, preciso que ao clicar num botão seja adicionado uma palavra especifica no local onde está posicionado o cursor, ou seja, tenho que pegar a posição do cursor no input e lá adicionar uma palavra.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: _"preciso que ao clicar num botão"_ - isso dificulta um pouco as coisas pois clicar fora do input faz ele perder o foco e o cursor já lá não está... Podes explicar o que queres fazer melhor?

Comment: Opa, bem pensado.

Durante o preenchimento do input será necessário que seja adicionado uma determinada palavra que mais tarde esse local com a palavra será substituída por outros valores.

No caso, o clique no botão será o metódo mais rápido para se adicionar tal palavra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fica uma sugestão:

Guarda a posição do cursor durante os `keyup` e assim sabes onde a ultima posição foi.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var caret = 0;
var texto = '_olá!_';
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    caret = this.selectionStart;
});
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var val = input.value;
    input.value = val.slice(0, caret) + texto + val.slice(caret);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wc2khavd/